# wxWidgets drawing clockwise elliptical arcs

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The [docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html#a821e0b82707ca0379273cca67913da06) for `wxDC::DrawEllipticArc` state:

> `start` and `end` specify the start and end of the arc relative to the three-o'clock position from the center of the rectangle. Angles are specified in degrees (360 is a complete circle). **Positive values mean counter-clockwise motion.**

So calling:

```
wxDC::DrawEllipticArc( ... 90, 270 )
```

Gives me:

[image]

Fair enough, the arc is drawn from 12o'clock to 6o'clock in the counter-clockwise direction.

Now I want to draw from 12o'clock to 6o'clock in the *clockwise* direction.  So I call:

```
wxDC::DrawEllipticArc( ... -90, -270 )
```

But I get the same result!

I have tried all sorts of combinations of +/-90 and +/-270 in different orders, but everything produces either the 12o'clock to 6o'clock in the counter-clockwise arc  ( usulally ) or a full circle ( sometimes )  I cannot find a combination to produce 'the other half'.

============ Fix ================

In my input data ( a DXF file ) the clockwise direction is indicated by an end angle less than the start angle.  So this code does the job

```
   if( ea < sa ) {
        // required to draw in clockwise direction
        // work arround for wxWidgets bug http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/4437
      ea += 360;
   }
    dc.DrawEllipticArc ( ... sa, ea );
```

wxWidgets 3.0.0 with gcc / codeblocks / mingw on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in this function, it's being discussed [here](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/4437) and the summary is that it's almost certainly buggy, but we just don't know how exactly to fix it yet. Please add your comments there.

This being said, I think you might be able to achieve the result that you need by drawing an arc from `270` to `450`...

Comment: Tried logging on to the trac bug tracker, but couldn't get past the captcha.  I think the DXF way of indicating clockwise ( start angle greater than end angle ) is better than mucking around with -ve angles.